# How to encode into WAV ADPCM?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, wav, pcm

**How to encode [WAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) PCM into WAV with [ADPCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_differential_pulse-code_modulation) encoding?**

I tried FFmpeg. I can see from the [old FFmpeg codec list](https://gist.github.com/viking/1933304), that it previously supported encoding into `adpcm_adx`, `adpcm_ima_qt`, `adpcm_ima_wav`, `adpcm_ms`, `adpcm_swf` and `adpcm_yamaha`. However, these codecs seem to be not included into FFmpeg anymore (at least, in my v.4.1.3 installation).

The purpose is to include a miniature audio file into an embedded project and then decode it with [dr_wav](https://github.com/mackron/dr_libs/blob/master/dr_wav.h) library, which supports IMA ADPCM and Microsoft ADPCM.

Comment: My copy of (Arch Linux built) ffmpeg 4.1.3 still lists all these codecs _and more_ (adpcm_g722, adpcm_g726) available for encoding under 'ffmpeg -codecs'. Could you clarify how you installed ffmpeg yourself, and include the output of **`ffmpeg -version`**?

Comment: @grawity, thanks for help! I was looking at `ffmpeg -formats | grep adpcm` instead of `ffmpeg -codecs | grep adpcm`. Silly me... And I also was using `-f` option instead of `-acodec`, so I got confused by `Requested output format 'adpcm_ms' is not a suitable output format` error... – Feel free to provide an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to close the question, here are two ways to convert audio into WAV with ADPCM encoding:

1) With FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.wav -f wav -acodec adpcm_ms OUTPUT.wav
```

2) With SoX:

```
sox INPUT.wav -e ms-adpcm OUTPUT.wav
```

Thanks to @grawity for the help!